# Mongoose redis can't find document keys

Tags: redis, mongoose

I have started using [mongoose-redis-cache](https://github.com/conancat/mongoose-redis-cache) for caching my queries. I have done everything that the documentation says. Still, I don't see the mongoose keys in redis client.

How to check if caching is working

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running test to ensure everything is installed properly?

## If you don't have Mocha installed already

npm install mocha -g

## Yeah, just get in there and get on it

cd tests
mocha